# startup class and main method for SkyLine

Tags: java

i need sample main method (for startup) with fake Data for this code (Skyline divide and conquer)

link : https://github.com/mouhyi/Algorithms/blame/master/SkyLine.java

Example code:

```
public static class runClass {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Building[] arr = {{1, 11, 5}, {2, 6, 7}, {3, 13, 9},
                    {12, 7, 16}, {14, 3, 25}, {19, 18, 22},
                    {23, 13, 29}, {24, 4, 28}};
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm requires an array of `Building` objects, not a 2-d array of integers. The `Building` class is defined inside the `SkyLine` class, so this is how you need to define your data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SkyLine.Building[] arr = new Building[] {
        new SkyLine.Building(1, 11, 5),
        new SkyLine.Building(2, 6, 7),
        new SkyLine.Building(3, 13, 9),
        new SkyLine.Building(12, 7, 16),
        new SkyLine.Building(14, 3, 25),
        new SkyLine.Building(19, 18, 22),
        new SkyLine.Building(23, 13, 29),
        new SkyLine.Building(24, 4, 28)
    };
}
```